# Remove vertical reversed duplicates from two vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I fill two vectors from a text file with two columns:

```
while (infile >> a >> b) {
    Alist.insert(Alist.end(), a);
    Blist.insert(Blist.end(), b);
}
```

So far so good, these vectors contain numbers such as:

```
Alist Blist
1     6
1     4
2     4
2     7
2     5
2     3
3     9
3     2
3     5
4     1
4     6
5     3
5     2
5     8
5     9
6     4
6     1
7     2
8     5
8     9
9     3
9     5
9     8
```

and I want to remove one of the couples such as `1 6` `6 1`. I want the `6 1` removed. There are more couples such as `1 4` `4 1`. How can I achieve this?

Just worked on this:

```
int g = 0, h =0;
for (int i = 0; i < Alist.size(); i++) {
    g = Alist[i];
    h = Blist[i];
    for (int y = 0; y < Blist.size(); y++) {
        if (Blist[y] == g && Alist[y] == h) {
            Alist.erase(Alist.begin() + y);
            Blist.erase(Blist.begin() + y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use std::erase, and a nice std::remove_if condition that checks if x1 = y2 and x2 = y1.

Comment: @SenselessCoder I just added some code at my initial post.

Comment: I think you can use a smarter approach. Is your vector sorted? If so, you can eliminate duplicates much more efficiently. I'd use binary search to find if there are duplicates, and simply remove them if so. Alternatively you can transform your structure to an std::map, as it also forces no duplicates.

Comment: Yes I can sort it. It's taking far to long to complete. How about that binary search?

Comment: The thing is this: Sorting takes O(NlgN) time. (You can use std::sort) Binary search only works on sorted elements. It's O(lgN). So for each element of the vector, you want to see if there exists a duplicate satisfying your condition. Then you can remove it manually. You can use std::binary_search. Link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Comment: The Alist is sorted by default. If sort Blist i'm losing the couple. For index 1  Alist is 1 but for Blist won't be 6.

Comment: Oh apologies. I thought they were one list of pairs. I'm dumb. In this case you really should be using an std::map. No need to store two seperate lists. Store an std::map of std::pair, the map will enforce uniqueness among the elments. You just need to supply a comparison object along with it.

Comment: Could I read the txt and store in a two dimensional vector and reverse the columns just for removing the duplicates. Because I want to remove the same but reversed couples. For example in `1 6` `6 1` remove the second.

Comment: @G90 How large is the input you're expecting?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's not known. Could be 10 could be 500.000 lines. This is a project for calculating triangles in networks. So the input is a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, one possible approach is using a `std::map` of pairs to ensure uniqueness (once a compare function is given). You can test for duplicates before adding a pair to the container, avoiding the search and erasures after.

```
#include <set>

using pair_int = std::pair<int,int>;

struct comp_pair {
    constexpr bool operator()(const pair_int &lhs, const pair_int &rhs) const {
        // compare the two pairs by their elements
        return lhs.first < rhs.first ? true : (
            lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second < rhs.second ? true : false);
    }
};

std::set<pair_int,comp_pair> ABlist;

while ( std::cin >> a >> b ) {
    // Assuming that A list is sorted, only pairs in which a > b can already
    // be present in the container as a (b,a) pair
    if ( a > b  &&  ABlist.find(std::make_pair(b,a)) != ABlist.end() )
        // if there is a match, go on without inserting anything
        continue;
    // insert a pair. The container grants for uniqueness
    ABlist.insert(std::make_pair(a,b));
}
```

This snippet, in a test program with the input example you gave, produces the following output:

```
1 4
1 6
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 7
3 5
3 9
4 6
5 8
5 9
8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

**First improvements, based on your inital code**

Your code doesn't take into account the case where `Alist[i]==Blist[i]`, which always get eliminated.  It also miss a multiple identical couple, as it doesn't take into account that the current position moves to the next item with the erase.  In the worst case, it could even go out of range in the inner loop, as the vector shrinks.

Note that reverse couples of items before `i` were already removed. You could use this to improve slighlty your algorithm, by starting the search for the reversed after the current position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Alist.size(); i++) {
    int g = Alist[i];
    int h = Blist[i];
    for (int y = i+1; y < Blist.size(); ) {  // start with next
        if (Alist[y] == h && Blist[y] == g) { 
            Alist.erase(Alist.begin() + y);
            Blist.erase(Blist.begin() + y);
        }
        else y++; // move to next only if current one was not erased
    }
}
```

The fact that `AList` is already sorted (according to your comments) makes sure that for 1 6 and 6 1  the second will be eliminated:

You could improve further by taking advantage of the sorted `Alist`: stop inner loop when over target, and enter in the loop only if ther's a chance to find something, i.e. if h>=g:

```
   if (h>=g)
        for (int y = i+1; y < Blist.size() && Alist[y]<=h; ) {  // start with next, stop if over target
             ...
        }
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/7Gqi4a)

**Further improvement**

You could eventually improve further by using a binary search to find the first occurence of `Blist[i]` in `Alist` .  Keep however the advantage of the previous pruning approaches, and use this ony as start value of y in the inner for loop.

Comment: What if the lists are not sorted and sorting is not an option since I would lose couples. By the way Alist[i] == Blist[i] is not an option for my list because it doesn't make sense. I checked it and this is not happening.

Comment: No problem then:  you can keep the code above without the last optimisation.  The only issue is that you're not sure whether you'll first meet 1 6 or 6 1.  This means that in the if-clause you'll either have to choos whether you delete the couple at i or the coulple at y, or you make a double-swap to make sure that the couple at y is the one with the smallest a component.

Comment: Keeping either couple at i or couple at y is not an issue as long as it deletes one of them.